# Self hosted multi user/account web mail client

Tags: email-client, webmail

I'm searching for a self hosted web mail client which can handle multiple mail accounts at one time, without logging in and out for switching.

Ideally the client is capable handing multiple user accounts where each user can access different mail accounts, like co worker A can access the service@example.com account and co worker B can access service account and it's own co-worker-b@example.com account.

A nice to have would be some kind of role management where a group of workers can access a mail account for sending and receiving but can't see or change the account credentials like the mail password.

Comment: There are dozens of options when selecting a webmail server application.  You should use one of those.

Comment: Why not use Horde.

Answer (score 0):

You're just looking for a web based mail client that supports multiple accounts?

Squirrelmail does that. You might need a plugin, it's unclear. Either way it should work.

http://squirrelmail.org/wiki/SquirrelMailFeatures